Cannot extract variance coefficient from R gls model from nlme
I am struggling with extacting the additive and proportial coefficients from this model.
fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary, weights = varConstProp(form = ~Time), control = list(sigma = 1))
print(fm1)


Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: follicles ~ sin(2 * pi * Time) + cos(2 * pi * Time)
  Data: Ovary
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -895.9725

Coefficients:
       (Intercept) sin(2 * pi * Time) cos(2 * pi * Time)
        12.1449478         -3.2724173         -0.9485432

Variance function:
 Structure: Constant plus proportion of variance covariate
 Formula: ~Time
 Parameter estimates:
    const      prop
 3.977779 -3.340088
Degrees of freedom: 308 total; 305 residual
Residual standard error: 1

So, I expect 3.97 and -3.34. However, on extracting them, I get:
fm1$modelStruct$varStruct$const
fm1$modelStruct$varStruct$prop

   const
1.380724
     prop
-3.340088


I think you need to exponentiate the estimated parameter: exp(1.38) returns [1] 3.974902
